# Reading from a txt file into a single array - Java

Tags: java, arrays, file-io

I have a txt file that contains 40 names. Each name is on its own line. This method should take each name and place it into an array of 4 elements and then take that array and write those files to another txt file with use of another method.

My issue is every forth name in the list somehow ends up being null and my output txt file ends up with 10 rows and a null as the forth element in each row.

I have provided code and sample I/O below. Thanks in advance!

Sample Input

```
Emily
Reba
Emma
Abigail
Jeannie
Isabella
Hannah
Samantha
```

My method

```
public static void fillArray(String[] player ,String[] team, BufferedReader br) throws IOException{
  String line;
  int count = 0;

  while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    if(count < 3){
       player[count] = line;
       count++;
    }
    else{
       count = 0;
       writeFile(player);
    }
  }
  br.close();
```

}

Sample Output

```
Emily Reba Emma null 
Jeannie Isabella Hannah null
```

Comment: What is your `writeFile()` and where do you call `fillArray()`?

Comment: Why are you stopping when `count < 3`? That block will only execute 3 times with the current coding.

Comment: am sure you are doing something extra index value in while printing !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect. `player[3]` is never set and the next loop you end up reading a line without storing it into the array. Use this:

```
public static void fillArray(String[] player ,String[] team, BufferedReader br) throws IOException{
  String line;
  int count = 0;

  while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
    player[count] = line;
    count++;
    if (count == 4) {
       count = 0;
       writeFile(player);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. That fixed it perfectly! I tend to over think sometimes.